# Word replacement for wordpress plugins

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to import a large quantity of products, the plugin is there and everything works, but I want to replace one word (different) in the product names with another word. 32,000 products, one product cannot be made.

I've tried different options, the only one that doesn't get into the wordpress error is the code below, but it doesn't work, I won't actually import the products.

** part between invalid

```
     protected function generate_product_data($product){
      $categories  = array_values(array_unique(array_map('trim', explode('>', $product['Category']))));
      $sku_prefix = get_option(PREFIX . '_sku_prefix', '');
      $images     = $this->get_images($product);
      $sku_raw    = $product['SKU'];
      $sku        = empty($sku_prefix) ? $sku_raw : "{$sku_prefix}{$sku_raw}";

      $webshop_price = empty(Utility::rgar($product, 'Webshop_price')) ? null : Utility::clean_price( $product['Webshop_price'] );
      $drop_price  = empty(Utility::rgar($product, 'drop_Price')) ? $webshop_price : Utility::clean_price( $product['drop_Price'] );
      $price         = $this->get_price($product);
  **
  function replace_text($replace){
     $replace = str_replace("badword", "goodword",$replace);
     $replace = str_replace("badword1", "goodword1",$replace);
     return $replace;}

  $data = array(
     'title'       => $product[replace_text('Product_title')],**
         'description' => $product['HTML_description'],
         'excerpt'     => $product['Properties'],
         'categories'  => $categories,
         'images'      => $images,
         'attributes'  => array(
            'Color'              => $product['Color'],
            'Gender'             => $product['Gender'],
            'Diameter'           => Product::measurements_number( $product['Diameter'] ),
            'Size'               => Product::measurements_number( $product['Size'] ),
            'Shipping_time'      => $this->get_shipping_time($product),
            'Number_of_packages' => $product['Number_of_packages'],
         ),
         'meta'        => array(
            '_regular_price'               => $price,
            '_price'                       => $price,
            'B2B_price'                    => Utility::clean_price( $product['B2B_price'] ),
            'RRP_price'                    => Utility::clean_price( $product['RRP'] ),
            'drop_price'                   => $drop_price,
            '_sku'                         => $sku,
            '_manage_stock'                => 'yes',
            '_stock'                       => $product['Stock'],
            '_stock_status'                => $product['Stock'] == '0' ? 'outofstock' : 'instock',
            '_weight'                      => Product::measurements_number( $product['Weight'] ),
            PREFIX . '_ean'                => $product['EAN'],
            PREFIX . '_sku_raw'            => $sku_raw,
            PREFIX . '_image_urls'         => $images,
            PREFIX . '_shipping_time'      => $this->get_shipping_time($product),
            PREFIX . '_parcel_or_pallet'   => $product['Parcel_or_pallet'],
            PREFIX . '_number_of_packages' => $product['Number_of_packages'],
         )
      );

      return $data;
   }
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Word replacement does not work. Imports only one product and no title.